# Meteor js parallel db fetch.

Tags: meteor

Let's say I have code which fetches data from multiple collections as follows.

```
//code running on server.
var a = collectionA.findOne({...});
var b = collectionB.findOne({...});
var c = collectionC.findOne({...});
var d = collectionD.findOne({...});
```

If I am not wrong above code will run in serial fashion. So waiting time to fetch a collection will add up and and response time will be delayed.

Is there a way to run above code in parallel fashion, preferably promise pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Meteor does not use promise or async, it uses Fibers.
You could use it directly or via methods.

With method it could look like this:

Serverside:

```
function fetchAFromDB(arg,cb){ //function needs a callbac
  var a = collectionA.findOne(arg);
  if (!a) {
    cb(new Meteor.Error("a-not-found", "Can't find a"));
  else
    cb(null,a) //first argmument is always an error
}

Meteor.methods({
 fetchA: function (arg) {       
   var fetchAAsync = Meteor.wrapAsync(fetchAFromDB); //wrap function as async
   var result = fetchAAscync(arg); //execute function
   return result; //return value
  }
}
//call method on the server
//async
Meteor.call('fetchA', {_id:'foo'}, function (error, result) { ... } );
//blocking 
var result = Meteor.call('fetchA', {_id:'foo'});
```

Call it clientside with:

```
Meteor.call('fetchA', {_id:'foo'}, function (error, result) { ... } );
```

Another way would be to use fiber directly ([Documentation for fibers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fibers)):

For your use-case it could look like that:

Serverside:

```
function doSomethingWith(a){...} //does something with a

var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers'); 
var async = Fiber(function() {  
    var a = collectionA.findOne({...});
    return doSomethingWith(a);
});

//calls you async function
async.run();
```